# Strange artifacts with pstricks plot

Tags: pstricks, pst-plot, adobe

Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[border=5pt,pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks,pst-plot,pst-math}
\listfiles

\begin{document}

\psset{xunit=1.05cm,yunit=1.05cm}
\begin{pspicture*}(-1.38,-2.28)(4.19,4.45)
   \psgrid[subgriddiv=0,gridlabels=0,gridcolor=lightgray](0,0)(-1.38,-2.28)(4.19,4.45)
   \psset{xunit=0.21cm,yunit=0.21cm,algebraic=true,dotstyle=o,dotsize=3pt
     0,linewidth=0.8pt,arrowsize=3pt 2,arrowinset=0.25}
   \psaxes[labelFontSize=\scriptstyle,xAxis=true,yAxis=true,Dx=5,Dy=5,ticksize=-2pt
   0,subticks=2]{->}(0,0)(-6.92,-11.39)(20.96,22.23)[x,140] [y,-40]
   \psplot[plotpoints=200]{-6.91776797358592}{-1.4000001}{(x^3-3*x^2-6*x+8)/(x^2-3.6*x-7)}
   \psplot[plotpoints=200]{-1.399999}{4.99999}{(x^3-3*x^2-6*x+8)/(x^2-3.6*x-7)}
   \psplot[plotpoints=200]{5.00001}{22.5}{(x^3-3*x^2-6*x+8)/(x^2-3.6*x-7)}
   \psline[linestyle=dashed,dash=2pt 2pt](-1.4,-11.39)(-1.4,22.23)
   \psline[linestyle=dashed,dash=2pt 2pt](5,-11.39)(5,22.23)
\end{pspicture*}

\psset{xunit=0.5cm,yunit=0.5cm}
\begin{pspicture*}(-7.87,-8.58)(10.82,6.44)
   \psgrid[subgriddiv=0,gridlabels=0,gridcolor=lightgray](0,0)(-7.87,-8.58)(10.82,6.44)
   \psset{xunit=0.5cm,yunit=0.5cm,algebraic=true,dotstyle=o,dotsize=3pt
     0,linewidth=0.8pt,arrowsize=3pt 2,arrowinset=0.25}
   \psaxes[labelFontSize=\scriptstyle,xAxis=true,yAxis=true,Dx=1,Dy=1,ticksize=-2pt
   0,subticks=2]{->}(0,0)(-7.87,-8.58)(10.82,6.44)[x,140] [y,-40]
   \psplot[plotpoints=200]{-7.75}{-4.73}{TAN(x)}
   \psplot[plotpoints=200]{-4.7}{-1.58}{TAN(x)}
   \psplot[plotpoints=200]{-1.56}{1.56}{TAN(x)}
   \psplot[plotpoints=200]{1.58}{4.70}{TAN(x)}
   \psplot[plotpoints=200]{4.72}{7.84}{TAN(x)}
   \psplot[plotpoints=200]{7.86}{11}{TAN(x)}
   \psline[linestyle=dashed,dash=2pt 2pt](1.57,-8.58)(1.57,6.44)
   \psline[linestyle=dashed,dash=2pt 2pt](4.71,-8.58)(4.71,6.44)
   \psline[linestyle=dashed,dash=2pt 2pt](7.85,-8.58)(7.85,6.44)
   \psline[linestyle=dashed,dash=2pt 2pt](-1.57,-8.58)(-1.57,6.44)
   \psline[linestyle=dashed,dash=2pt 2pt](-4.71,-8.58)(-4.71,6.44)
\end{pspicture*}

\end{document}
```

When printing this document from Adobe Reader 11.0.12 on a Windows 7 machine, artifacts as in the picture below appear:

[image]

However, they do not show up in the viewer. I do not get them when printing from OS X's Preview.app or from Foxit Reader on a Windows 8.1 machine. The issue does not seem linked to the print driver, as it happens with different printers.

The problem originally appeared in a document created by a friend of mine, I just took it over. She uses MikTeX 2.9 (and some not really up-to-date versions of PS Tricks), I tried it with TeX Live 2014 on a Mac and TeX Live 2015 on Windows 8.1. My package versions are

```
pstricks.sty    2013/12/12 v0.60 LaTeX wrapper for `PSTricks' (RN,HV)
pstricks.tex    2014/10/25 v2.60 `PSTricks' (tvz,hv)
pst-xkey.tex    2005/11/25 v1.6 PSTricks specialization of xkeyval (HA)
  pst-fp.tex    2014/10/25 v2.60 `PST-fp' (hv)
pst-plot.sty    2011/04/13 package wrapper for pst-plot.tex (hv)
pst-xkey.sty    2005/11/25 v1.6 package wrapper for pst-xkey.tex (HA)
pst-plot.tex    2014/08/23 1.70 `pst-plot' (tvz,hv)
pst-math.sty    2014/07/30 package wrapper for PSTricks pst-math.tex
```

What makes the issue even stranger is the fact that in the TAN-plot, the problem only appears in the bottom right corner:

[image]

Even though this seems to be an Adobe problem, I still ask the question on TeX.SX, hoping that someone knows a workaround. The thing is: my friend has to give the PDF to someone who *will* print it with Adobe reader, so changing the reader is not a solution.

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem printing with Acrogat Reader DC.

Answer (score 1):

With an up-to-date TeXLive 2015 you'll get

```
\documentclass[border=5pt,pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\listfiles

\begin{document}

    \psset{xunit=1.05cm,yunit=1.05cm,plotpoints=200}
    \begin{pspicture*}(-1.38,-2.28)(4.19,4.45)
    \psgrid[subgriddiv=0,gridlabels=0,gridcolor=lightgray](0,0)(-1.38,-2.28)(4.19,4.45)
    \psset{xunit=0.21cm,yunit=0.21cm,algebraic,linewidth=0.8pt,arrowsize=3pt 2,arrowinset=0.25}
    \psaxes[labelFontSize=\scriptstyle,Dx=5,Dy=5,
      ticksize=-2pt 0,subticks=2]{->}(0,0)(-6.92,-11.39)(20.96,22.23)[x,140] [y,-40]
    \psplot{-6.91776797358592}{-1.4000001}{(x^3-3*x^2-6*x+8)/(x^2-3.6*x-7)}
    \psplot{-1.399999}{4.99999}{(x^3-3*x^2-6*x+8)/(x^2-3.6*x-7)}
    \psplot{5.00001}{22.5}{(x^3-3*x^2-6*x+8)/(x^2-3.6*x-7)}
    \psline[linestyle=dashed,dash=2pt 2pt](-1.4,-11.39)(-1.4,22.23)
    \psline[linestyle=dashed,dash=2pt 2pt](5,-11.39)(5,22.23)
    \end{pspicture*}

    \psset{xunit=0.5cm,yunit=0.5cm}
    \begin{pspicture*}(-7.87,-8.58)(10.82,6.44)
    \psgrid[subgriddiv=0,gridlabels=0,gridcolor=lightgray](0,0)(-7.87,-8.58)(10.82,6.44)
    \psset{algebraic,linewidth=0.8pt,arrowsize=3pt 2,arrowinset=0.25}
    \psaxes[labelFontSize=\scriptstyle,ticksize=-2pt 0,
      subticks=2]{->}(0,0)(-7.87,-8.58)(10.82,6.44)[x,140][y,-40]
    \multido{\rA=-7.75+3.1415}{6}{\psplot{\rA}{\rA\space 3 add}{TAN(x)}}
    \multido{\rB=-4.71+3.1415}{5}{\psline[linestyle=dashed,dash=2pt 2pt](\rB,-8.58)(\rB,6.44)}
    \end{pspicture*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Herbert. I don't quite get it: The PDFs actually do look like this with my TeX Live 2014 and 2015, and even with my friend's Miktex. However, when printing the images, the straight lines appear -- but only under certain circumstances. If I print her file from my Mac, it is all fine. If she prints it at home from Foxit, its good. If she prints it on the school's computer (Windows 7, Adobe Reader), it's bad.

Comment: please send me your dvi, ps and pdf by private mail

Comment: I am glad to do so. Just to make sure....are you who I think you are: the author of "Grafik mit PostScript für TeX und LaTeX"? I am confused, because of your profile (Hanoi, age 19).

Comment: The first one is correct :-)